# Is there a terminal command to set a GIF as a wallpaper in MacOS?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, terminal, catalina

I have tried to use the third-party GitHub apps and other solutions but none of them work. I really want it to work as I have some cool GIFs that would really rekindle the feeling of customisation on a Mac.

Comment: Are you talking about a macOS Desktop Background?

Comment: Yes! I need some terminal code to set the desktop background. The apps like GIFPaper don't work. Btw do I have to disable csrutil to use it?

Comment: OK. What is your ultimate aim here? Are you trying to change the background on the login screen? Are you trying to change the background once logged in as a user? Are you trying to setup a user background slide-show kind of effect? In general, user background screens are controlled by System Preferences > Desktop & Screen Saver.